# Remove margin from OutlinedButton with circle shap - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter and now creating an outlined button with a circle shape.

Description: I created a sample project for this button. I expect a circle button with an icon and clickable. But when I created this button with OutlinedButton and modified its style to a circle. it seems there is an extra margin around the button.

Question: I tried to set its fixed size, but no effect. How should I remove this margin?

[image]

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Flutter App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: const CircleBorder(eccentricity: 0),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                foregroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.add,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
          )) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a margin, it is the default size of styleFrom when minimumSize is null, in the case of ElevatedButton.styleFrom the default is width: 64.
The solution is to set minimumSize and remove the padding.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text('Flutter App'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Row(),
          const Text('BEFORE'),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: const CircleBorder(eccentricity: 0),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              foregroundColor: Colors.green,
              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          const Text('AFTER'),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: const CircleBorder(eccentricity: 0),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              foregroundColor: Colors.green,
              tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
              side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
              minimumSize: const Size(40, 40),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]